# Why DCM doesn't work in Modelsim 10.3?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, modelsim

I tried to use Digital Clock Manager (DCM) and double the input clock. iSim (Xilinx simulation tool) gives the correct result, but in Modelsim the output clock is always zero.

I always compile the unisims folder (that consist of IBUFG, DCM and BUFG modules in xilinx software) in the library of my project in modelsim.

---

According to the Russel Answer I used Xilinx Core Generator. I want the frequency of `CLKFX` to be double of `CLKIN`. As you see in the following pictures, the results of iSim (Xilinx simulator) is correct, but in Modelsim  `CLKFX` is always zero :

iSim results (Xilinx Simulator) :

[image]

Modelsim results :

[image]

Comment: Did you write the verilog for DCM, how is the model or code available to modelsim?

Comment: The unisims folder (in xilinx) consists of DCM , BUFG and IBUFG modules (verilog code). I compiled the folder in the library of my project in modelsim. (C:\Xilinx\14.2\ISE_DS\ISE\verilog\src\unisims)

Comment: A DCM can take up to 160 us to produce an stable output clock. Have you simulated such a long period of time?

Comment: In iSim after 15 cycles ( if T = 100 ns after 1500 ns ) the output clock is provided, but in modelsim I run 200 micro second (2000 cycles) and no changes was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you're not setting up the DCM correctly, you need to read the documentation about DCMs and how they work.  If you search for Xilinx Library Guide (+FPGA Name) you'll find all of the Primitives that are available in your device.  Or you can look at the full list here:

[Xilinx Library Guides](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/ise_n_libraries_guides.htm)

If you're still having trouble after looking at all of your parameters, you can try using CoreGen to generate your DCM for you.  CoreGen will ensure that you do not make any mistakes or instantiate something in an invalid configuration.  The output of CoreGen is a .vhd file that you can drop into your modelsim project and simulate with that.

Comment: Thank you Russell. I used Core Generator (Xilinx tool) and create a single DCM. The output `CLK0` is correct but `CLKFX` and `CLK2X` doesn't work in modelsim. They are always zero !

Comment: Do you see any modelsim warnings when you compile your code or load the simulation?  If modelsim cannot find the DCM it will create a black box and you might see this behavior.  Look through your modelsim warnings very carefully.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no warning or error in the modelsim Transcript. As you said I created DCM with Core Generator several times. Always the number of warnings or errors is zero, and the output `CLK0` is similar to input `CLKIN`, but the output `CLKFX` is always zero. Frequency of `CLKFX` should be double of `CLKIN`.   (I edited my question with results of iSim and Modelsim simulators)

Comment: @Amir, what Xilinx FPGA Family are you using?

Comment: FPGA Spartan3 - 3s400

Comment: You need to wire up CLKFB on your DCM.  From the Library Guide, "On-chip synchronization is achieved by connecting the CLKFB input to a point on the global clock network
driven by a BUFG, a global clock buffer. The BUFG connected to the CLKFB input of the DCM must be sourced
from either the CLK0 or CLK2X outputs of the same DCM."

So take your CLK2X output and wire it up to CLKFB.

Comment: Inside my DCM module (is created with Core Generator) a IBUFG is added at the left hand and a BUFG at the right hand of the DCM by Core Generator and `CLKFB` is feed with the output of the BUFG. BUFG's input is feed with `CLK0`. Should I do something else ?

Comment: At this point your best bet is to open a webcase with Xilinx.

Comment: I could get the correct result. It was related to IBUFG, DCM and BUFG modules. I changed the timescale in the modules. Default was pico second, I was changing it to nano second. It was my fault. Thank you so much Russel. Core Generator was a good idea.

Comment: @Amir, good find!  Yes I forgot about that!  The resolution definitely needs to be smaller for the DCM to work.  I'm glad you got to the bottom of it.  I'm actually a bit surprised that Modelsim did not give you a warning about that.